# ANT JS select not displaying values reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am new to react. I need a select in my webpage.
I have an array which looks like this,

```
databaseList =  ["information_schema", "ResumeParser", "analystor", "analystor_check", "mysql", "performance_schema", "plugin_testing", "sys", "wordpress"]
```

I want to map this array to `Select`.
In normal `Select` in HTML, it works,
Here's the code,

```
<select >
    <option value='None'>None</option>
    {
        this.state.databaseList.map((database) => {
            return (<option value={database}>{database}</option>)
        })
    }
</select>
```

But in `Ant JS select`, it shows error,
Here's the Ant js code,

```
<Select mode="single" placeholder="Please select Database" style={{ width: '370px' }}>
    {
        this.state.databaseList.map((database) => {
            return (
                <Option value ={database}>
                    {database}
                </Option>)
        })
    }
</Select>
```

Error I got:
[image]

I don't know what i am doing wrong in AntJS select. I gone through Ant JS docs but can't fix my problem. Help me with some solutions.

Comment: Make sure there is no blank value in the `state.databaseList` array (if the array is being updated). Try logging the array before `Select` rendering.

Comment: @Prakash Sharma, but in normal select code, it displays the values in dropdown. In antjs select code, it fails.

Comment: Please show the whole code... Show a producible example and not snippets

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you need to validate your data list ```{ this.state.databaseList && Array.isArray(this.state.databaseList) && this.state.databaseList.map```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work, the only problem is that `databaseList` may be `undefined`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    databaseList: [
      'information_schema',
      'ResumeParser',
      'analystor',
      'analystor_check',
      'mysql',
      'performance_schema',
      'plugin_testing',
      'sys',
      'wordpress'
    ]
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Select
        mode="single"
        placeholder="Please select Database"
        style={{ width: '370px' }}
      >
        {Array.isArray(this.state.databaseList) &&
          this.state.databaseList.map(database => {
            return <Option value={database}>{database}</Option>;
          })}
      </Select>
    );
  };
}
```

[image: Edit Q-58789528-UndefinedSelect]

Comment: you don't need to provide a default value, that undefined is unnecessary.